# What was the Lubavitcher Rebbe's approach to rebuke?

Tags: chabad, chassidic-rebbe, rebuke-tochacha

Did it differ from when he was giving to others and from when he was telling others to give it? There's always the stories of him being very loving and reaching out to every Jew and emphasizing ahavat Yisrael, etc.. and the general approach of Chabad seems to be not to push.

Comment: Are you asking about a Hasidic rebbe? One of the rebbes of habad? What sort of stories are you referring to? Could you add a link to an example?

Answer (score 2):

The Rebbe's approach to rebuke is the same approach stated explicitly by the Alter Rebbe in chapter 32 of the Tanya, Likkutei Amarim since he is [ממלא מקוםו](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15970&st=&pgnum=348), like is taught generally by all the Rebbes of Lubavitch.

> שחלק מהם כבר נדפס [מתחיל מתורה אור לרבינו הזקן (שנדפס בדור הצמח צדק והיה מוכן לדפוס כבר בזמן אדמו״ר האמצעי) וגם בדרושי אדמו״ר האמצעי (אשר לפעמים נעתק בהם לשון אדמו״ר הזקן עצמו), וכן בדרושי רבותינו נשיאינו **ממלאי מקומו**] כו׳

Chapter 32 of Tanya teaches:

> What about the statement in the Talmud that if you see your colleague sinning you must hate him, and also tell his teacher so that he should hate him as well?
>
> That's talking about someone who is your peer, who learns Torah and
>   does all the mitzvahs. He did something that he should have realized
>   is wrong and you rebuked him for it, as the Torah instructs you,
>   "Rebuke, you shall rebuke your comrade." The word for comrade used
>   here is "amitecha." Who is amitecha? The Talmud tells us that this
>   means those people who are with you in Torah and mitzvahs.
>   Nevertheless, this friend of yours still has not repented from his
>   sin. This is how the situation is described in Sefer Charedim.
>
> Let's say, however, this person is not your comrade in Torah and you
>   are not close with him. In that case, Hillel the Elder instructs you
>   to "be of the disciples of Aaron: love peace...love those that were
>   created and attract them to Torah." He was speaking of those who are
>   far from G‑d's Torah and from being observant Jews—which is why he
>   calls them just "those that were created." He was saying that you must
>   pull in these people with thick cords of love, and perhaps, with all
>   this effort, perhaps you will attract them to Torah and to the service
>   of G‑d. Perhaps yes, perhaps not. Whatever the outcome, you have not
>   lost the reward for showing love to a fellow Jew.

*With you in Torah and mitzvot* means at the same level and station as yourself. Additionally, the expression *comrade* means you must have a close relationship with that person.

Comment: How do you know his approach is the same? Do you have a source?

Comment: This is a general teaching of all the Rebbes of Chabad. They are מלא מקום of the previous Rebbe of each generation all the way back to the Alter Rebbe. The principle is repeated in so many of his ma'amarim that for anyone who learns them, it would be difficult not to trip over it.

Comment: Is it really the case that there is never an argument between Lubavitchers Rebbe? If not, I'm not sure how you've proven from that quote that Rebbe #7 agreed with Rebbe #1.

Comment: @mevaqesh Per your request, a citation has been provided. For you to understand the idea completely you should learn the entire linked ma'amar.  It is excellent and fully sourced with citations as you like it.

Comment: @DoubleAA You too should learn the linked ma'amar completely. Then you might understand.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I suspect I have better things to do with my time. Try to avoid giving a reference that we can't understand without learning extensive chassidic discourses.

Comment: @DoubleAA I provided, as requested, a specific citation from the Rebbe stating the idea that all the Rebbes are ממלא מקום of the previous Rebbe all the way back to the Alter Rebbe. The discourse explains in detail what that means and that each generation adds to but does not subtract from the previous Rebbe's teachings. Unless you or mevaqesh have a specific citation from the Rebbe saying he doesn't agree with the teachings of the Alter Rebbe, then the objection is unfounded. And your suspicion that you have better things to do with your time is incorrect.

Comment: "as requested, a specific citation from the Rebbe stating the idea that all the Rebbes are ממלא מקום of the previous Rebbe all the way back to the Alter Rebbe" That isn't what was requested. If you are proving that Rebbe #7 agreed with Rebbe #1 because they never argued, that's a valid argument form, though I'm skeptical if it's actually true. Aren't there differences of opinion among the Rebbes on issues like sleeping in the Sukkah or Chadash? Perhaps I'm mistaken. That's why I asked above "Is it really the case that there is never an argument between Lubavitchers Rebbe?"

Comment: @DoubleAA Like I said, try learning the discourse. You want a deeper understanding. Try looking at the Rebbe's own teaching about it. It is what he teaches about this concept in his own words, not my opinion. And as I understand the site guidelines, it isn't my job to prove the teaching of any cited source.

Answer (score 1):

Reb [Yoel Kahn](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F) (One of the biggest Chassidim in America) [wrote](http://www.shturem.net/index.php?section=news&id=62689) a letter to Reb [Mendel Vechter](http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%9C_%D7%95%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%9B%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%A8) (A Satmar Chassid who was becoming Lubavitch).

(Note, it's a twenty some pages long!)

[image]
[image]

He wrote (in short) that the Rebbe's approach was that our job is to bring back Jews to Judaism, and if it has to be done through love, so be it.

Comment: What defines a person as being "one of the biggest Chassidim in America"?

Comment: @Chaim size :) . No, but a Chozer who is the main Mashpia in the main Yeshiva in Lubavitch should show that he knows something.